# Paying for an on hold airline ticket without an itinerary receipt or confirmation number

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, bookings

I wasn't able to print my itinerary receipt in Cebu Pacific and my status was still on hold, I clicked something and my itinerary receipt disappeared. I don't even know my confirmation number so I can't view the receipt, what will I do? It said that I have until 23:59H PH to pay but how will I pay?

Answer (score 6):

If you really can't go back to that page, and you don't know how to find cached Internet files, try calling them. If your booking is held, they should be able to access it and accept payment.

(This isn't really a travel question, more a support question regarding a web application)

Comment: Correct, I have had an airline website hang after I click Confirm and when I called, they could find the pending reservation and process the rest of it over the phone.